# How to Google "::" (double colon)

Tags: google-search

I would like to search for answers to a problem related to a code issue in PHP with `Class::method`.

While I was searching for answers I realised Google seems to drop the `::` in all search queries.

The answers are all without the double colons. Even single colons will get dropped for the searches.

**How can I search for double colons in google?**

Comment: (Btw, these are "colons", not "dots".) I was going to suggest wrapping the search phrase in double quotes (exact match), but whilst this does change the search results, it still appears to omit the double-colon. Even enabling "Verbatim" search still appears to omit the double-colon. (?)